# What is phenotyping of blood during transfusion process?

Tags: hematology, blood-transfusion

Thallaesemic patients are advised to have only "[phenotypically matched blood](http://nbts.gov.eg/pages/Phenotyping.html)".I mean the transfusion problems arise mainly due to "grouping problems" like mismatch b/w ABO & Rh+/- so what do this phenotyping mean? Isn't "grouping" of blood enough?

*Statutory declaration- the link provided in the q is only to clarify in which context the q is asked & nothing more, like promoting Egyptian Gov. Health Service*...(or any other CRAZY INTERPRETATIONS like that)**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a special process of the egyptian blood transfusion service, which we will not be able to answer.

Comment: excuse me....but I think you need to delve deeper into a q b4 u make such....naive comment.....Indian blood transfusion process also follows this....& if you really want to , then try to get through Wintrobe's Clinical Hematology (which is not possible for me at my stage)....

Comment: I do not think this question should be closed since I know a similar advice is dispensed in many middle eastern countries!

Answer (score 1):

In response to the above q. many have commented that the process is *only limited to Middle Eastern countries*....I think the term '*only*' will be better substituted by '*mainly*', the reason to which , is explained later ....

Now, the main clarification lies in the fact that,

> ....there are more than 600 known antigens besides A and B that
>   characterize the proteins found on a person's red cells. A combination
>   of some of these less familiar but commonly occurring antigens are
>   absent from the blood of an extremely small percentage of the
>   population. There are also a few antigens that almost all people have
>   on their red cells but that some lack. - [One In A Million
>   American Rare Donor Program](http://web.archive.org/web/20080621091025/http://www.newenglandblood.org/medical/rare.htm)

Now patients receiving a 1st time transfusion normally do not show any reactions or cross-matching problems with these blood subgroups but during repeated transfusion process like in case of thallaesemia , the receiver's blood gets sensitized against the donor's blood & the problems ensues...

> [Dr Therese Callaghan](http://www.blood.co.uk/the-donor/summer2014/phenotyping/) said, “All other antibodies are unexpected and
>   are of two distinct types, alloantibodies (which target an antigen
>   that is not present on your own red blood cells) and autoantibodies
>   (which target an antigen that is present on your own cells).
>
> “Patients receiving a transfusion for the first time do not normally
>   have problems with matching blood types and antigens. However it is
>   during subsequent transfusions when more care needs to be taken. If,
>   during a later transfusion, the blood contains the same antigens as an
>   earlier one, the patient’s immune system recognises the transfused
>   blood cells as ‘foreign’ and the antibodies (formed after the first
>   transfusion) will destroy the blood cells the patient has been given.
>   This is called a transfusion reaction and can cause serious illness or
>   even death if not treated quickly. That is why matching the blood
>   phenotype is so important.”

Now coming to "**Why mainly in Middle-East ??"**

These rare blood groups are distributed into major 30 discrete system, which **mainly  are present in different ethnic groups & communities**...mainly living in Middle-Eastern states & Asia...& also in African countries...
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3353626/table/T3/

Intersted people may also check the following articles (or simply search Google)

[To Provide Phenotype-Matched Red Blood Cells or Not – That is the Question!](http://scabb.org/blog/to-provide-phenotype-matched-red-blood-cells-or-not-%E2%80%93-that-is-the-question/)

[13.3: Pre-transfusion testing](http://www.transfusionguidelines.org.uk/red-book/chapter-13-patient-testing-red-cell-immunohaematology/13-3-pre-transfusion-testing)- Joint United Kingdom (UK) Blood Transfusion and Tissue Transplantation Services Professional Advisory Committee

& for a complete picture plz browse through- [Immunohaematology](http://www.cartercenter.org/resources/pdfs/health/ephti/library/lecture_notes/med_lab_tech_students/LN_Immunohaematology_final.pdf)